# Add event handler to whole column cells with button

Tags: javafx

How to add same event handler to whole table column in `JavaFX` api?
I want to add a same event handler to all buttons added to the column cells.
I added buttons in column cells of the table with the help of for loop.

Comment: Define the eventhandler outside of the loop and set it to buttons in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

declare an EventHandler

```
EventHandler handler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(InputEvent event) {
        // do something 
        event.consume();
    }
};
```

for each button

```
btn.setOnAction(handler);
```